# Javascript hours of operation computer timezone

Tags: timezone

I have a display on my intranet page that shows the hours of operation of each department. The problem is that the departments and users are spread out across Canada. I want to be able to display the HoO for each department based on the users' computer time, in a div tag. So as an example:

Billing 08:00 to 17:00 eastern.
Customer service 07:00 to 16:00 mountain.
Technical support 09:00 to 20:00 pacific.

If a user from Calgary (mountain) goes to the page they will see:

Billing 06:00 to 15:00
Customer service 07:00 to 16:00
Technical service 10:00 to 21:00

but if a user from Vancouver opens the page they will see the hours based on their computer's timezone setting.

Also, I want to be able to put another div next to each department that changes between "open" and "closed" based on those hours.

I've searched for this example but so far I can only find a script to display open/closed based on set hours. Meaning, if the computer timezone is that hour then it shows open, whether the HoO is actually for that region.

I appreciate any information on this.
Chester

Comment: Show what you have tried.  Your question is understandable, but you haven't shown any effort.  You can't just list your requirements and expect us to give a complete solution.  StackOverflow is not a code-for-hire service.

Comment: Sorry about that Matt. I totally forgot to put in the code I had, but I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, as Matt mentioned I forgot to put in the code I was using, but I think I figured it out. I realized I should be using the getTimezoneoffset() to determine the user's PC time zone, then add some if statements to display the hours. Here is the code I used, I'm sure there's a cleaner way to write this out, I don't mind your feedback:

```
var d new Date();
if (d.getDay() > 0 && d.getDay() < 6) { // Check if Monday to Friday
     var openHour = 5;
     var closeHour = 17;
}

var timezone = (d.getTimezoneoffset() / 60 - 6)*(-1), //Turn time zone into an integer to add it to display time
     ohours = d.getHours(d.setHours(openHour + timezone)).toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
     chours = d.getHours(d.setHours(closeHour + timezone)).toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
     oampm = d.getHours(d.setHours(openHour + timezone)) >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
     campm = d.getHours(d.setHours(openHour + timezone)) >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

var display = "Currently Closed";

if (!(isNaN(openHour)) && !(ht < openHour || ht > closeHour)) { //If openHour is empty or between openHour and closeHour
     display = 'Open today from '+ohours+':00 '+oampm+' to '+chours+':00 '+campm;
}

document.getElementById("dayWeek").innerHTML = days[(new Date).getDay()];
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = display;
```

Then I used div id to display the two elements:

```
<h1><span id="dayWeek"></span> Hours</h1>
<div id="para1"></div>
```

The output looks like this (based on the current day and time) since it's Sunday it's closed:

**Sunday Hours**
Currently Closed